# Laravel Nginx 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: laravel, nginx, nginx-config

I have tried to deploy the Laravel application using Nginx web server. However, I get the 502 Bad Gateway error. I have checked the default file located in the sites-available folder and made some changes.

Following code snippet shows the default site configuration file.

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html/laravel/skill-tool-app/public;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name 18.130.196.144;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404 /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}
```

I have checked file permissions as well. When I try to access the website. It makes the browser download the index.php file.

Answer (score 1):

you should have to enable php from this config file:

Please update your location block:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    # PLEASE UPDATE php version with your current installed version
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

Whole file should look like:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  root /var/www/html/laravel/skill-tool-app/public;

  # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
  index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

  server_name 18.130.196.144;

  location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404 /index.php?$query_string;
  }

  # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
  #
    location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  }

  # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
  # concurs with nginx's one
  #
  #location ~ /\.ht {
  #       deny all;
  #}
}
```

Comment: You must need to install it first. `sudo apt install php7.0-fpm`.

Answer (score 0):

cut defatult_server.unblock some section I giving in below

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  root /var/www/html/laravel/skill-tool-app/public;

  # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
  index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

  server_name 18.130.196.144;

  location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404 /index.php?$query_string;
  }

  # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
  #
    location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  }

  # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
  # concurs with nginx's one
  #
  location ~ /\.ht {
         deny all;
  }
}
```

Now you need to enable the configuration, make a symlink to the enabled sites:

```
ln -s /etc/sites-available/YOUR_FILE_NAME /etc/sites-enabled/
```

then

```
sudo systemctl reload nginx
```

or

```
service nginx restart
```